# How can I un-subtheme a theme?

Tags: 6, theming

I've been developing a custom theme as a Zen subtheme, but I've made so many changes and new files that nothing from the original Zen theme is being used.

However, my new theme is still connected to the Zen theme and requires that it is installed on the server.

How can I detach the Zen parent theme and have my subtheme stand alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove “base theme” declaration from YOURTHEME.info

Comment: Dont forget to add "engine = phptemplate" (or whatever engine you use), if it isn't already listed in the .info